# error: could not convert ‘((const MyClass*)this)->MyClass::myLabel’ from ‘QLabel* const’ to ‘QLabel’

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to return a QLabel from a function, but I keep getting the error:

```
/media/root/5431214957EBF5D7/projects/c/qt/tools/plugandpaint/plugins/extrafilters/extrafiltersplugin.cpp:17: error: could not convert ‘((const ExtraFiltersPlugin*)this)->ExtraFiltersPlugin::retLabel’ from ‘QLabel* const’ to ‘QLabel’


                ^~~~~~~~
```

**extrafiltersplugin.h**

```
#ifndef EXTRAFILTERSPLUGIN_H
#define EXTRAFILTERSPLUGIN_H

#include <interfaces.h>

#include <QObject>
#include <QtPlugin>
#include <QImage>
#include <QLabel>

class ExtraFiltersPlugin :
        public QObject,

        public FilterInterface,
        public RevViewsInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.Qt.Examples.PlugAndPaint.FilterInterface" FILE "extrafilters.json")
    Q_INTERFACES(FilterInterface RevViewsInterface)

public:
    ExtraFiltersPlugin();

    // RevInterface
    QLabel label() const override;

private:
    QLabel *retLabel;
};

#endif
```

**extrafiltersplugin.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "extrafiltersplugin.h"

ExtraFiltersPlugin::ExtraFiltersPlugin() {
    retLabel = new QLabel();
    retLabel->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Sunken);
    retLabel->setText("first line\nsecond line");
    retLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight);
}

QLabel ExtraFiltersPlugin::label() const
{
    return retLabel;
}
```

What could it be that I'm doing wrong or missing? I'm a total C++/ Qt newbie, if this seems completely obvious.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You're trying to return a pointer `retLabel` from a function that returns an non-pointer object.

Comment: That was already answered in a comment by @some-programmer-dude to your previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049893/error-label-was-not-declared-in-this-scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return a `QLabel` (or an instance of any `QWidget` derived class) by value as they can't be copied.

You need to change the signature of `ExtraFiltersPlugin::label` so that it returns either a pointer...

```
QLabel *ExtraFiltersPlugin::label () const
{
  return retLabel;
}
```

or a reference...

```
QLabel &ExtraFiltersPlugin::label () const
{
  return *retLabel;
}
```

Note that both of the above allow the caller to modify the referenced `QLabel`.  If that's not needed (or desired) then the return type should be `const QLabel *` or `const QLabel &` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

label() defined in header to return a QLabel but later in implementation, label() return a pointer to a QLabel.

Solution:

Update implementation of label() [ in cpp file ] to return a QLabel object:

```
QLabel ExtraFiltersPlugin::label() const { return *retLabel; }
```

Updating the signature of ExtraFiltersPlugin::label() will not work because function is decorated as override;